# New Ionic 7 Cordova project with - livereload does not work and give an error as “ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE”

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5

Steps to Reproduce:

I create a new angular based starter - blank - Ionic 7 project via

`ionic start testapp`

I then added the cordova android platform with the following command:

`ionic cordova platform add android`

I run the following command to do a livereload:

`ionic cordova run android -l`

it compile and install device successfully. But after app start splash screen have appeared then give error as following screen.

[image]

My ionic info as following:

```
`Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 7.1.5 (C:\Users\POLAT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 7.5.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 16.2.10
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 16.2.10
   @angular/cli                  : 16.2.10
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 7.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 12.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 3 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 2.0.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\POLAT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v18.18.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 10.2.3
   OS                : Windows 10`
```

when I run the following command:

`` `ionic cordova run android` ``  or `ionic cordova run android -l --external` it is work successfully. But I will use "navigator.mediaDevices" in my project. If I use --external parameter in my command, "navigator.mediaDevices" is undefined. Without -l and external parameter, "navigator.mediaDevices" is work as expected. So I need to work with `` `ionic cordova run android -l` `` command.